# React Native - Dynamically added Picker Value Updates and Goes Back To Initial value

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

I have been trying to get native base picker to work on button click, when ever i click a button, i want to add two new text fields and two new picker, at the moment, i can add the text fields and they work correctly, but i cant figure out how to make the picker selected value stay, the pickers are added, but when i select a value,the value does not stay. i have searched google and i got some code but still yet i cant get it to work.

I have tried many codes i saw online but none seem to have worked exactly the way i need to work even after tweaking the codes.

this is the function that generates the fields dynamically

```
addTextInput = (index) => {
let textInput = this.state.textInput;
let IndexNumber = index;
let Pickeholder = "Aircraft";
textInput.push(
<View>
    <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
      onChangeText={(text) => this.addValues(text, index)} />

      { this.state.OtherMission && 
         <Item floatingLabel style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
        <Label> Other Mission</Label>
        <Input onChangeText={MissionType => this.setState({MissionType})}/>
        </Item> } 
        <Item style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
            <Text  style={{ marginLeft: -4, color : "#4166f5" }}> Aircraft {'\n'} {'\n'}</Text>
              <Picker style={{ width: 100,marginLeft: -64,marginTop: 20 }}
              iosHeader="Select one"
              mode="dropdown" 
              //selectedValue={Pickeholder}
             selectedValue={this.state.AircraftType[index].text.toString()}
             // onValueChange={this.onSetAircraftValue.bind(this,index,IndexNumber)}>
              //onValueChange={(selectedText) => this.setState({searchText: selectedText})}>
                onValueChange={(selectedText) => this.addAircraftType(selectedText, index)}>
             <Item label="Select Aircraft" value="Select Aircraft" />
              <Item label="40" value="40" />
              <Item label="42" value="42" />
              <Item label="228" value="228" />
              <Item label="Super" value="Super" />
            </Picker>
      </Item>

       <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <Item floatingLabel style={{width: '30%', marginTop: 10 }} >
            <Label  style={{ color : "#4166f5" }}>Flight Hours</Label>
            <Input  style={{ marginTop: 10 }}  maxLength = {5} keyboardType='numeric' onChangeText={(text) => this.addHours(text, index)}/>
          </Item>

          <Item floatingLabel style={{ width: '30%',marginTop: 10 }} >
            <Label  style={{ color : "#4166f5" }}>Minutes</Label>
            <Input  style={{ marginTop: 10 }}   maxLength = {2} keyboardType='numeric' onChangeText={(text) => this.addMinutes(text, index)}/>
          </Item> 
         </View>
     </View> 
  );
this.setState({ textInput });
```

}

this is the state code for state

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {

   textInput : [],
   AircraftType : [ { "index": 0, "text": "42", },],
   FlightHrs : [],
   FlightMins : [],
   AircraftCurrency : [],
       inputData : [],
  }; }
```

and this code successfully sets the state but the picker is not updating, or rather it updates and goes back to initial value.

```
addAircraftType = (text, index) => { 
let dataArray = this.state.AircraftType;
let checkBool = false;
if (dataArray.length !== 0){
  dataArray.forEach(element => {
    if (element.index === index ){
      element.text = text;
      checkBool = true;
    }
  });
}
if (checkBool){
this.setState({
  AircraftType: dataArray
});  }  else {
dataArray.push({'text':text,'index':index});
this.setState({
  AircraftType: dataArray
});    } }
```

Comment: Can you provide expo snack?

Comment: Really dont know how to do that now, am a newbie in react native.

Comment: Please take a look at the code and tell me what i might need to do or other ways i can provide more clue. I really need to get this working.